# Compile OpenCV code with icc and mmic flag

Tags: opencv, icc

I need to use OpenCV+FFMPEG in a Xeon Phi without root permission.

My environment is:

OpenCV version: 3.1.0
Host OS: Linux
Target OS: Phi Co-Processor
Compiler & CMake: ICC 15.0.2 & CMake 3.5.2 (installed in my home)

When I compile OpenCV with GCC in my home, it works fine. I compile with

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/lib/opencv-3.1.0 -D WITH_GTK=ON ..
```

all works fine by setting LD_CONFIG_PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH env variables od ffmpeg and opencv.

Now, i need to use my code in a PHi CoProcessor, so I compile my code with

```
icc -mmic -Wall -std=c++11 -DNO_DEFAULT_MAPPING -I /home/spm1407/lib/opencv-3.1.0/include/ -I /home/spm1501/fastflow/ -O3 -o farm farm.cpp -pthread -L/home/spm1407/lib/opencv-3.1.0/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_video -lopencv_imgproc -lpthread
```

(Please ignore FastFlow)

Compiler returns

```
x86_64-k1om-linux-ld: skipping incompatible /home/spm1407/lib/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_core.so when searching for -lopencv_core
x86_64-k1om-linux-ld: cannot find -lopencv_core
x86_64-k1om-linux-ld: skipping incompatible /home/spm1407/lib/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_highgui.so when searching for -lopencv_highgui
x86_64-k1om-linux-ld: cannot find -lopencv_highgui
x86_64-k1om-linux-ld: skipping incompatible /home/spm1407/lib/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so when searching for -lopencv_imgcodecs
x86_64-k1om-linux-ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs
x86_64-k1om-linux-ld: skipping incompatible /home/spm1407/lib/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_videoio.so when searching for -lopencv_videoio
x86_64-k1om-linux-ld: cannot find -lopencv_videoio
x86_64-k1om-linux-ld: skipping incompatible /home/spm1407/lib/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_video.so when searching for -lopencv_video
x86_64-k1om-linux-ld: cannot find -lopencv_video
x86_64-k1om-linux-ld: skipping incompatible /home/spm1407/lib/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so when searching for -lopencv_imgproc
x86_64-k1om-linux-ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgproc
```

if i omit mmic flag, compiler works fine.

How can i resolve this issue? Any suggest? 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?